# Why is crontab sending me emails when 'grep' hasn't found a matching string?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Using Linux as my web server and using github for VCS.
In the crontab, I've configured it to execute the below command every minute and to send me an email when the string "error" was found in the piped result.

```
cd /home/project/repo1 && git pull | grep "error"
```

While it does 'git pull' successfully, it's incorrectly sending emails when it pulls new changes to the repo.

Here's the body of the email:

```
From ssh://github.com/project123/repo123
   3332bqzd..1234dz4 main       -> origin/main
```

Strangely, it's not sending me email when the output of git pull is "**Already up to date.**"

Why is cron sending me emails when there's no string 'error' in the output?

Comment: I think to help, we'd need to see some more context. What does your crontab look like and how is the logic to send the email triggered?

Comment: `MAILTO="duke@example.com"                                                                                         PATH=/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin:/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin                            #IWORX-DISABLED#*/5 * * * * /usr/sbin/relax php -f /chroot/home/project/repo/html/wp-cron.php                */1 * * * * cd /home/project/repo/html && git pull | grep "error"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `git` is outputting stuff to `stderr`. For example, try `git pull > /dev/null`. You'll see the output is still printed.

Try:

```
git pull 2>&1 | grep "error"
```

This will redirect all of `git`'s output to `stdout`, then pipe it to `grep`.